# MySQL Stopping an Event in Triggers

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

How do you stop an `Event` in a trigger. For Example: I have this simple code below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkPlayer BEFORE INSERT ON players

BEGIN

  DECLARE ctr INT;

  SELECT count(*) 
    INTO ctr 
    FROM players 
   WHERE fName = NEW.fName 
     AND lName = NEW.lName;

  IF ctr > 0 THEN
    -- LEAVE and don't insert because player exists
  END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) for such things:

> SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or to the client. Also, it provides control over the error's characteristics (error number, SQLSTATE value, message). Without SIGNAL, it is necessary to resort to workarounds such as deliberately referring to a nonexistent table to cause a routine to return an error.

Any [error conditional in a BEFORE trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) (including, AFAIK, an appropriate `SIGNAL` value) will abort the trigger and the statement that triggered the trigger. If your version of MySQL doesn't support `SIGNAL` (i.e. your version is less than 5.5) then you'll have to trigger an error in another way such as the old "select from a table that does not exist" hack or the ["violate a PK by a double INSERT"](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints) hack.

I only have 5.1 handy so I can't verify the `SIGNAL` stuff. The relevant section of "19.3.1. Trigger Syntax" is the same for 5.1, 5.2, and 5.5 though so one of the "trigger an error" kludges should work if you need to resort to such things.

Comment: Thanks mate, i've been looking for a word to search and that was actually the "SIGNAL" you said, really helps

Answer (score 1):

I have a mini blog post explaining signals with sample code. Click [here](http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/mysql-5-5-signals/). Also instead of generating an exception by inserting two entries with the same primary key, you could also use the divide by 0 exception which involves no insert statements into the database.